# jsTree "select_node" returns false

Tags: jstree, selectnodes

I am using jsTree in angularjs and using "select_node" in "ready". This method is returning false. On code debugged, it is observed that tree.instance._model.data doesn't have that node so this.get_node(obj); returns false. (below is code snippet)

```
select_node : function (obj, supress_event, prevent_open, e) {
        var dom, t1, t2, th;
        if($.isArray(obj)) {
            obj = obj.slice();
            for(t1 = 0, t2 = obj.length; t1 < t2; t1++) {
                this.select_node(obj[t1], supress_event, prevent_open, e);
            }
            return true;
        }
        obj = this.get_node(obj); //here it returns false
        if(!obj || obj.id === '#') {
            return false;
        }
}
```

I am not sure why tree.instance._model.data doesn't have data at that time because it often works when I refresh the browser.

Any help? Below is my code snippet.

```
me.onTreeReady = function (eve, tree) {
   tree.instance.deselect_all();
   tree.instance.refresh(true, true);
   var response = tree.instance.select_node(defaultNode); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be some kind of race condition related to your angular directive provider.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I had added "id" to html, so when multiple instances were created with same id it gives the above error. Issue resolved by removing this id.

Old Code

```
<div class="row no-margin" cg-busy="ctrl.promise">
    <div class="bg-white">
        <div **id="treeView"** js-tree="ctrl.treeConfig"
             should-apply="ctrl.applyModelChanges()"
             ng-model="ctrl.treeData"
             tree="ctrl.treeInstance"
             tree-  events="ready:ctrl.onTreeReadyEvent;select_node:ctrl.onNodeSelectEvent;deselect_node:ctrl.onNodeDeselectEvent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

New Code:

```
<div class="row no-margin" cg-busy="ctrl.promise">
    <div class="bg-white">
        <div js-tree="ctrl.treeConfig"
             should-apply="ctrl.applyModelChanges()"
             ng-model="ctrl.treeData"
             tree="ctrl.treeInstance"
             tree-  events="ready:ctrl.onTreeReadyEvent;select_node:ctrl.onNodeSelectEvent;deselect_node:ctrl.onNodeDeselectEvent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```